# Problem to assign string literal to std::wstring

Tags: c++

I have a problem with std::wstring in C++. 
This doesn't work:

```
std::wstring s="foo";
```

This works:

```
std::wstring s=L"foo";
```

Swagger Codegen generates a lot of C++ code that doesn't use the L prefix, so that I don't want to add a "L"-prefix for every string literal.
Is there a way that

```
std::wstring s="foo";
```

is accepted by the compiler?

My Setup:
Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop
Windows 10 Pro

Comment: No, there's no facility for automatic conversion of char strings to wchar_t strings.  You'll need to call a function that can do the conversion.

Comment: *I don't want to add a "L"-prefix for every string literal.* -- Well, I think it's time to enhance your code generator or update it to handle `wchar_t` strings.

Comment: The compiler can't do this automatically. The type of the string literal and the wide character type don't contain any information about how the string contents are encoded. So there is no way to do the necessary decoding and encoding automatically.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It's an official code generator from Swagger: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen

Comment: @StefanDeller Then it's time to open an issue with them on github or request an enhancement.

Comment: Unrelated: unless you've got  a good reason like working on a legacy system or enjoy suffering for no good reason, consider updating your version of Visual Studio. There are some  really groovy improvements to both the IDE and the compiler over the years. Just moving up to 2015 is a huge leap forward.

Comment: Stack Overflow usage note: Be very careful with the next few questions to make sure they are new and interesting. The number of poorly received questions, zero score or less, you have asked greatly exceeds the number of well received questions and could trigger a severe reduction in the frequency at which you can ask questions.